# How to set gradle properties for all my android projects?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to set gradle properties for   all my android projects?
I have diffrent  android projetcs but whenever i change my gradel.properties file in  project folder  it only affect that projects.
And i cannot find the gradle.properties in  .gradle folder  in root directory.
  How do i set common properties for all projects so i dont need to change everytime.

Comment: Do you mean across different projects in the same multi-project build or across all projects on your specific system?

Comment: no not in multi projects ,  i want to save changes in all  projects in my system

Answer (score 9):

Gradle supports system-wide properties in a `gradle.properties` file in the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` directory, which defaults to a folder called `.gradle` in your home directory, e.g. `C:\Users\<user>\.gradle` on Windows.

These system specific properties may override project specific properties, so they can be used to specify usernames and passwords only for your local machine.

This global `gradle.properties` may not exist by default, but even if not, you can create one and it will be used and the properties will be available in your build script.

If your global settings require more logic than just plain properties, you can use *initialization scripts*, which can be placed in the same location (or the `init.d` subdirectory).

Answer (score 4):

For MacOS users:

1. Open terminal and enter `cd ~/.gradle`
2. Do a `ls` to check whether `gradle.properties` already exists or not
3. If it doesn't exist, create one: `vi gradle.properties`.
4. If it exists, just modify the configs you want to modify and save it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer

> This global gradle.properties may not exist by default, but even if not, **you can create one** and it will be used and the properties will be available in your build script.

Create one in C:\Users\user-name.gradle  and name it `gradle.properties` without any extensions.

Answer (score 1):

**Documentation :**

> Project properties are inherited from parent to child projects.

**Root Project**

```
ext{
    supportLibVersion = '25.3.1'

    //supportLib
    supportLib = "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
}
```

**Child Projects:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //supportLib
    compile rootProject.ext.supportLib
}
```

Comment: i want to set my  gradle. daemon true  in all projects and provide  large   heap size  but i need to do  changes in all the projects.. How can i set common for all

Comment: you can define variable for its value in root project and use that variable as value in projects. Check how I defined supportLib variable and used it

Answer (score 0):

According to Gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties) you can set a project property through an environment variable. All you need to do is to prepend the environment variable with `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT` and Android Studio loads it as a project property for all the Android (and Gradle) projects. Example:

```
echo 'export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_foo=bar' >> ~/.zshenv
```

And you can access this as project property in build.gradle files:

```
def fooProperty = project.foo
println("Foo property is $fooProperty") // prints bar
```

**Note:** Make sure you restart Android Studio after adding the environment variable so that the property is correctly loaded.